# twin vs deep_twin, is_equal vs is_deep_equal

Tags: eiffel

What is the difference between `twin` and `deep_twin` which implies (and ensures) the difference between `is_equal` and `is_deep_equal` in eiffel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`twin` makes a copy of the current object. If the object references other objects, by default it does not make copies of these other objects. That's why it is said that the function makes a "shallow" copy. On the contrary, `deep_twin` makes a copy not only of the current object, but also (recursively) copies of all other objects that are referenced by the current one. Here is an example

```
class A create make feature
   make (value: STRING) do item := value end
   item: STRING
end

a: A
...
a.item = a.twin.item -- Evaluates to True
a.item = a.deep_twin.item -- Evaluates to False
```

In the first comparison, the value of `item` in the twin is the same string object as in the original object. In the second comparison, the value of `item` in the twin is a new string object, equal to `a.item`. In other words, if `a.item = s`, then `a.twin.item = s`, but `a.twin.item = s1` where `s1 /= s`, but `s1 ~ s`.

`is_equal` and `is_deep_equal` are conterparts for the functions above. The first makes a "shallow" equality test, the second — a deep one. In the example, we have

```
a.is_equal (a.twin) -- Evaluates to True
a.is_deep_equal (a.twin) -- Evaluates to True
a.is_equal (a.deep_twin) -- Evaluates to False
a.is_deep_equal (a.deep_twin) -- Evaluates to True
```

If objects are "shallow" equal, they are also "deep" equal. But the reverse is not true.

All the above is valid with the assumption that the default versions of `is_equal` and `twin` are used. The features can be redefined to go deeper. For the class above we can add

```
   is_equal (other: like Current): BOOLEAN
      do
            -- The default version is "Result := item = other.item"
         Result := item ~ other.item -- Compare content rather than references
      end

   copy (other: like Current) -- twin is defined in terms of this procedure
      do
            -- The default version is "item := other.item"
         item := other.item.twin -- Use a copy instead of the reference
      end
```

With this redefinition, `twin`/`deep_twin` and `is_equal`/`is_deep_equal` become almost the same.